# Multiline regex in pdf file

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I am interested in extracting some information from some PDF files that look like [this](https://www.oni.navy.mil/News/Shipping-Threat-Reports/Archive/FileId/16152/). I only need the information at pages 2 and after which looks like this:

1. (U) country: On [date] [text]. (text in brackets)

This means it always starts with a number a dot a country and finishes with brackets which brackets may also go to the next line too.

My implementation in python is the following:

1. use pdfminer extract_text function to get the whole text.
2. Then use re.findall function in the whole text using this regex `^\d{1,2}\. \(u\) \w+.\w*.\w*:.* on \d{1,2} \w+.*$` with the re.MULTILINE option too.

I have noticed that this extracts the first line of all the paragraphs that I am interested in, but I cannot find a way to grab everything until the end of the paragraph which is the brackets (.*).

I was wondering if anyone can provide some help into this. I was hoping I can match this by only one regex. Otherwise I might try split it by line and iterate through each one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update the pattern using a negated character class matching until the first occurrence of `:` and then match at least `on` after it.

To match all following line, you can match a newline and assert that the nextline does not contain only spaces followed by a newline using a negative lookahead.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
^\d{1,2}\.\s\(u\)\s[^:\n]*:.*?\son\s\d{1,2}\s.*(?:\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\n).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{1,2}\.\s\(u\)\s` Match 2 digits, `.` a whitespace char and `(u)`
- `[^:\n]*:` Match any char except `:` or a newline, then match `:`
- `.*?\son\s` Match the first occurrence of `on` between whitespace chars
- `\d{1,2}\s` Match 1-2 digits and a whitespace char
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\n).*` Match a newline, and assert not only spaces followed by a newline
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/04P48N/1)

For example

```
pattern = r"^\d{1,2}\.\s\(u\)\s[^:]*:.*?\son\s\d{1,2}\s.*(?:\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\n).*)*"

print(re.findall(pattern, extracted_text, re.M | re.I))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks a lot. It seems you can do anything if you know how to do it with REGEX. By the way amazing explanation and the regex demo looks very good. I will read it in depth to see if I understand completely how you thought about this pattern.

Comment: By the way do you know why it does not catch the following examples completely like the others? They dont look any different than the ones that are catched as expected. The one is 2. (u) peru: on 9 september, a duty crewman on routine rounds onboard a container ship anchored near position 
and the other is
1. (u) papua new guinea: on 7 september, two suspected pirates were arrested by local authorities on                                                                                                                                It looks like it was cut and did not catch until the brackets.

Comment: @conclv_damian When I check this in the regex101 demo it seems to work. See https://regex101.com/r/B2DSLX/1

Comment: Yes in newest regex demo link you have put it by hand at the beginning and it catches it. Although, in both links for example it does not catch it as it is in the text. If you go to the end of the text in the 'papua new guinea:..' for example you will see it is not caught.

Comment: @conclv_damian The `^` asserts the start of the string. If you omit that, it will also match in the text.

Comment: To be honest I still don't see in the demo that it catches the examples I mentioned. By the way what was the idea in the non matching group? For example you want to match a \n hence it means end of the line, but you want to ensure that then this follows by some text and not some more white spaces or new lines which would mean another paragraph. Then you have the repeat * which means as much text it finds UNTIL another \n. So you are trying to catch the continuous lines that are followed by text and not white spaces. Finally, you close non capturing group and add a repeat * to do this untilFail

Comment: where fail is actually a new line followed by white spaces or new lines and not text. Although, I still cannot get it why you use a non capturing group like this.

Comment: @conclv_damian The non capture group is to repeat the part as a whole. The negative lookahead makes sure to only match lines continuous lines that are not "empty". Can you create a regex101 link with some examples that you want to match?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238945/discussion-between-conclv-damian-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: Hi, check this regex101.com/r/NHKv91/1 for example. And go towards the end of the text where it says "1. (U) PAPUA NEW GUINEA: On 7 September, two suspected pirates were arrested by local authorities on " This should match until (PNG–Post Courier) but it does not. This is what I meant.  Finally, I understand that Non Capture Group asserts that a \n is not followed by another \n or \s but since it is a Non Capture Group how does it return these lines? Shouldn't it skip them?

Comment: @conclv_damian The paragraphs are divided by an empty line. In your example about the text with papua, how do you know if the following lines are not a paragraph? See https://regex101.com/r/HrQHr2/1

Comment: Because, I know that when something starts lets say as "1. (U) PAPUA NEW GUINEA: On 7 September ..." Then this paragraph needs to end when a .(dot) and brackets with text follow such as (PNG-Post Courier). For example, in the regex demo that you just sent, indeed you catch the bracket (PNG-Post Courier) but if you look at other examples it is wrong and does not catch it as well as the 1st solution you posted.

Comment: @conclv_damian That is exactly my point :-) If you want to match those as well, you will have to write a pattern that takes those scenario's into account. Let's me see if we can handle that part.

Comment: @conclv_damian You might take the parenthesis at the end into account https://regex101.com/r/3M9Zhp/1